# Total count of strings within range in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where I want to count the total number of occurrences of the word `Yes`, as it appears between a range of rows—`Dir`—and then add that count as a new column.

```
Type,Problem
Parent,
Dir,Yes
File,
Opp,Yes
Dir,
Metadata,
Subfolder,Yes
Dir,
Opp,Yes
```

So whenever the word `Yes` appears in the `Problem` column between two `Dir` rows, I need a count to then appear next to the `Dir` at the beginning of the range.

Expected output would be:

```
     Type   Problem     yes_count
   Parent       
      Dir       Yes             2
     File       
      Opp       Yes 
      Dir                       1
 Metadata       
Subfolder       Yes 
      Dir                       1
      Opp       Yes
```

I could do something like `yes_count = df['Problem'].str.count('Yes').sum()` to get part of the way there. But how do I also account for the range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
# is the row a "Yes"?
m1 = df['Problem'].eq('Yes')
# is the row a "Dir"?
m2 = df['Type'].eq('Dir')
# form groups starting on each "Dir"
g = m1.groupby(m2.cumsum())
# count the number of "Yes" per group
# assign only on "Dir"
df['yes_count'] = g.transform('sum').where(m2)
```

Output:

```
        Type Problem  yes_count
0     Parent     NaN        NaN
1        Dir     Yes        2.0
2       File     NaN        NaN
3        Opp     Yes        NaN
4        Dir     NaN        1.0
5   Metadata     NaN        NaN
6  Subfolder     Yes        NaN
7        Dir     NaN        1.0
8        Opp     Yes        NaN
```

Comment: The `yes_count` should only display in the `Dir` rows though.

Comment: @user53526356 then it's easier, just mask on the fire values, see update

Comment: I meant "Dir", not "fire" (autocorrect)